debian isc dhcpd same host declaration multiple ip multiple interfaces
I'm facing troubles configuring isc dhcpd server. My network configuration is microsegmentation and I have to reserve multiple ip with multiple nic on the same host. I've already tested different configuration but the error is the same " Only one fixed address declaration per host." or "already exists".
I've tried to declare in those ways:
1
host dp03-wazuh.dognet.tech {
        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:DE:E5:0C;
        fixed-address 172.16.0.22;

        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:93:74:ED;
        fixed-address 172.16.16.21;

        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:A0:05:E4;
        fixed-address 172.16.32.21;

        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:17:BF:65;
        fixed-address 172.16.48.22;

        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:FA:91:01;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.4;
}

2
host dp03-wazuh.dognet.tech {
        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:DE:E5:0C;
        fixed-address 172.16.0.22;
}
host dp03-wazuh.dognet.tech {
        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:93:74:ED;
        fixed-address 172.16.16.21;
}
host dp03-wazuh.dognet.tech { 
       hardware ethernet BC:24:11:A0:05:E4;
        fixed-address 172.16.32.21;
}

host dp03-wazuh.dognet.tech {
        hardware ethernet BC:24:11:17:BF:65;
        fixed-address 172.16.48.22;
}
host dp03-wazuh.dognet.tech { 
       hardware ethernet BC:24:11:FA:91:01;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.4;
}

3
Create 5 file .conf for each nic with the host declaration and then on dhcpd.conf insert the include "/etc/dhcp/host_reserved_eth*.conf"

All the configurations tested don't works, somebody has any idea?
Thanks in advance
